# Python - Pillow: getcolors() sorting

Tags: python, sorting, python-imaging-library

I am trying to get a list with all the colors from the image below, which I easily managed by just using the getcolors() function and only keep the results with an occurence value above a certain treshold.
However, the resulting list is in a semi random order. Is there an elegant way to get an output that matches the order left to right?
One way I am thinking about is scanning the middle horizontal row on a pixel-by-pixel basis and add the results to the list every time a new color is discovered. But this isn't very elegant imo... How does Pillow decide the scanning order and how can I get it to go left-right?

[image]

Comment: I think Pillow doesn't care of order. You have to do it on your own sort it. So use your idea.

Comment: Do you know anything more about the image than you have told us? For example, are there always 26 circles? Or do you know how many circles there are for each image? Are they always the same area/size?

Comment: Convert to a different color space and sort based on intensities present on resulting channels

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the result is not semi-random ordered. It is ordered from the lightest color to the darkest. The idea you have come up with is the best one in my opinion.